# Intellij Idea doesn't create web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, servlet-3.0

When i create my web application project. I can not choose version of the web application. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krXN7.png)

Answer (score 1):

Issue is reported to YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180393
As a workaround, please create web.xml file in Web facet settings of the created module: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/web-facet-page.html